# Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function

Tags: javascript, block-editor, import, plugin-jetpack, sass

I built a plugin that registers a Gutenberg block that prints a simple Mailchimp form. The plugin works with no issues. But, if I activate Jetpack and try to edit any page or post, I get a blank screen and multiple `Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function` console errors such as this one with little variations:

```
editor.js?ver=9.1:6 Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function (https://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/_inc/blocks/editor.js?ver=9.1)
    at editor.js?ver=9.1:6
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.exports (editor.js?ver=9.1:6)
    at f (editor.js?ver=9.1:6)
    at Module.<anonymous> (editor.js?ver=9.1:18)
    at o (editor.js?ver=9.1:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (editor.js?ver=9.1:18)
    at o (editor.js?ver=9.1:1)
    at editor.js?ver=9.1:1
    at editor.js?ver=9.1:1]
```

The `index.js` file in My Mailchimp block plugin imports two SCSS files so the build process is able to create the corresponding CSS files:

```
import './editor.scss';
import './style.scss';
```

I found that if I comment out the `import './editor.scss'` line, Jetpack stops throwing the console errors. So, it seems there's something in my plugin that is conflicting with Jetpack.

Am I importing the SCSS files incorrectly in my code? Can someone help me, please? I'm completely lost.

I'm running WP 5.5.3 and I have the SCRIPT_DEBUG constant set to true.

Thanks

Comment: And your scss files only contain (valid) SCSS and no JS? How do you process them (ie does webpack put all CSS then in a separate file or similar)?

Comment: No JS code. I tried with both valid SCSS code and no code at all with the same results. I'm using the official wp-scripts build method (which uses a predefined webpack.config.js file) which processes style.scss into index.css and editor.scss into style-index.css.

Comment: Okay, strange. Did you check the file from Jetpack, try to find out if it is using some global variable that you're overwriting (and hence dropping it being a function) or similar? All in all, this question seems better fit for the official Jetpack support forums